# Named Credentials - Refresh Token - Google APIS

Tags: api, oauth2, oauth

I am getting following error on trying to OAuth with Google APIs, using Named Credentials. This error comes after doing OAuth dance via

1. Setup > Named Credentials 
   or
2. My Settings > Authentication Settings for External Systems

[image: My Settings > Authentication Settings for External Systems]

To get refresh token, I added access_type=offline at the end of AUTH url (pic below). But its not working out.

[image]

Anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 5):

In the Auth. Provider, set Provider Type to 'Open ID Connect' (not 'Google'), and in 'Authorize Endpoint URL' put 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force'. In Named Credential, include 'openid' as the first scope, you can add any other Google scopes after that.
Read more:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/sso_provider_openid_connect.htm